# initialize an instance in objective-C with alloc and init

Tags: objective-c

I am learning Objective-C and I've just read about alloc and int methods. Before this point,when I wanted to create an instance of NSDate for example, I coded:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
```

Now I saw that the above can be written like this

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

Are the above do the same thing? As i have understood (hopefully correct) the first one creates and instance of NSDate, by sending the message date to the class NSDate. The second one, it just allocates space for the instance and initialize it, so that it is ready to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would think the two things you list were definitely not the same thing based on a background knowledge of Objective-C, if you weren't familiar with NSDate. But in fact, they are the same thing in this case.

`[NSDate date]` is calling an NSDate class method that returns an NSDate object set to the current date and time.

Normally, a method call like `[[NSDate alloc] init]` would instantiate a new default object of the type requested, so you might expect that this would not be set to any date/time. However, the default NSDate object is in fact initialised with the current date and time, [as discussed in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/init), so in this particular case—they *are* the same thing.

As an aside, as with most NSObjects, you can also just call `[NSDate new]` to get the same effect as `[[NSDate alloc] init]` (and thus the same effect in this case as `[NSDate date]`).